# Problem with the display of the heatmap on jupyter: it crushes the old graphs of other measures

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

when I display the distributtion plot it works just fine and I get my graph displayed.

```py
sns.distplot(df['Price'])
```

when I add a new code line to display the heatmap of the `corr`:

```py
sns.heatmap(df.corr())
```

it Crushes my old graph and get displayed at its place.
can't get both graphs displayed at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You can try displaying multiple images in Jupyter notebooks with the [`IPython.display.display()`](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.display.html#IPython.display.display) method. IPython is the python shell used by Jupyter notebooks, so you can import it without installing any external libraries. Just wrap your plots inside the function like you would with a `print` method:

```
from IPython.display import display

display(sns.distplot(df['Price']))
display(sns.heatmap(df.corr()))
```

Comment: Following on hhimko's suggestions... Another way is to make sure you are invoking your plots in different cells. Also see examples similar to the dataframes plots you describe [here](https://nbviewer.org/github/fomightez/cluster_analysis-binder/blob/master/Hierarchical_clustering.ipynb). How I display them may give you some ideas to try to get closer to what you seek.